# How do you alter the description of a struct column on a BigQuery table?

Tags: google-bigquery

If you have a table with a struct and want a SQL script to alter the description of the column in the metadata?
For example, if I want to change the Location.Description on the table below from "*Loc Desc*" to "*Location Description*" what SQL do I need?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE MyDataset.MyTable
(
  ID INT64 NOT NULL,
  Location STRUCT<ID INT64 OPTIONS(description="Location ID for Event"), 
                  Description STRING OPTIONS(description="Loc Desc")> OPTIONS(description="Event Location Record")
);
```

I've tried this but it does not work:

```
ALTER TABLE MyDataset.MyTable 
ALTER COLUMN Location.Description 
SET OPTIONS(description="Location Description");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need alter the column at the Location level

```
ALTER TABLE MyDataset.MyTable
ALTER COLUMN Location
SET OPTIONS(description="Event Location Record",
            fields="ID:INT64:NULLABLE:Location ID for Event,
                    Description:STRING:NULLABLE:Location Description");
```

Comment: Does not work, after looking at the documentation I don't think you can currently set options for subfields with an alter statement. See: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#alter_column_set_options_statement "column_name: The name of the top level column you're altering. Modifying subfields, such as nested columns in a STRUCT, is not supported."